# Removing the extra values of Picklist in salesforce DB

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-service-cloud

*How to the remove the extra values of Picklist(which already exists in DB) in salesforce DB*? Perhaps, something I want to achieve below like this:
Remarried change to Married
Divorced change to Single
Engaged changed to Single
Separated change to Married

*Specific question: Can we update values without SOCL query? What are the ways to do this?*

PS: Apologies for the basic question, as I'm naive in salesforce.

Any inputs in this regard is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get the SOQL query. Updating here for benefit of others

```
    //Remarried change to Married
//Divorced change to Single
//Engaged changed to Single
//Separated change to Married
//Query for single record

//Updating multiple Records:
//Retrieve list of contacts, whose Marital_Status__c is Remarried, Divorced, Engaged, Separated
List<Contact> martialType = [Single];

//Loop through those contacts and set Marital_Status__c accordingly
for (Contact contUpdateObj: martialType) {

    //SET operation for Remarried to Married
    if(contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c == 'Remarried') {
        contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c = 'Married';
        //System.debug('FirstName= ' + contUpdateObj.FirstName);
        //System.debug('Updated values are = ' + contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c);
    }
    //SET operation for Divorced to Single
    if(contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c == 'Divorced') {
        contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c = 'Single';
        //Printing logs on console
        //System.debug('FirstName= ' + contUpdateObj.FirstName);
        //System.debug('Updated values are = ' + contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c);
    }
    //SET operation for Enaged to Single
    if(contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c == 'Engaged') {
        contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c = 'Single';
         //Printing logs on console
        System.debug('FirstName= ' + contUpdateObj.FirstName);
        System.debug('Updated values are = ' + contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c);
    }
     //SET operation for Separated to Married
    if(contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c == 'Separated') {
        contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c = 'Married';
        System.debug('FirstName= ' + contUpdateObj.FirstName);
        System.debug('Updated values are = ' + contUpdateObj.Marital_Status__c);
    }
}

//Run a DML update statement, now all account records in the list will have type updated accordingly
//Remarried change to Married
//Divorced change to Single
//Engaged changed to Single
//Separated change to Married
//Query for single record
update martialType;
```